# PHP mssql_bind failure

Tags: php, sql-server, php-mssql

I've got a stored procedure in MSSQL that takes 2 input parameters.  @ID int = 0 and @TYPE varchar(20) = 'Employee'

Calling this stored proc from PHP with no input parameters works fine.  Calling it with the parameters in Management Studio works fine.  The problem I run into is in mssql_bind-ing the @TYPE input parameter.

I have verified that my connection and statements are setup correctly as I can call the stored procedure just fine as long as I don't bind anything.  If I do mssql_bind, the request fails immediately as if there is a syntax error and the page isn't being interpreted correctly.  Even with ini_set('display_errors', 1) and error_reporting(E_ALL) set, I get no errors.  The page just fails.

Here is the code for the MSSQL connection.

```
$statement = mssql_init("Stored_Procedure", $mssql_connection);
mssql_bind($statement, '@TYPE', 'Applicant', SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 20);
$results['applicants'] = mssql_execute($statement)
```

Like I said, these statements work just fine without the mssql_bind.  With that in there the page fails to load instantly without error.  If anyone has any idea what might be going on here, I'd love to hear it!  Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass values to mssql_bind. You have to pass a variable. Assign the value 'Applicant' to a variable $type, and pass the variable.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see this answer, well, a long time ago. That certainly did the trick!